# Customize menu bar in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way to customize the menu bar in Notepad++? For the toolbar there is the creatively named plugin "Customize Toolbar", but for the menu bar I can't find anything, not even a config file.
I would like to remove entire menus (like "Window") and single entries (like "Launch in Firefox").
If there is a way to just get the menu bar to not wrap in slim windows, that would also be nice, but full customization is preferred.

Comment: You may be able to modify the [jN-npp-plugin](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jn-npp-plugin/) to delete menu items (it can add menu items). Source code is available for the plugin.

Comment: If you're on Windows, then the config file is likely in your user-specific data folder, something like C:\Users\YOURUSERID\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\plugins\config

Comment: No, there is no file for the menu bar. What plugin do you mean and what's the file name? Also, @DavidPostill, I asked and jN-npp can't remove menu items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way of removing menu items, it's using Resource Hacker.
But keep in mind that there are some syntax highlighting problems, such as if you re-open Notepad++, you'll see that you don't have syntax highlighting, until you re-open that file. I know it's just awful but there is no fix (as for now, I think).

First of all, download Resource Hacker from [this source](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/reshacker_setup.exe).

Install it and navigate to Notepad++ Executable which should be located at 
**C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe** or **Program Files** if you are on 64-Bit.

Now you want to copy the original Notepad++ executable to desktop, but also rename the one inside Notepad++ folder to notepad++.exe.bak or notepad++_ORIGINAL.exe. Doing so will save you from re-installing in case you screw something up.

Now onto your desktop. Right click on notepad++.exe and click **Open with Resource Hacker**. You should get plently of options there, but what we care about is removing the menu, so navigate to **MENU** and remove the following items: **1500**, **1501** & **11000**:
[image]

After you've removed the MENU items completely, now choose the **Save As** option and save the file onto desktop as notepad++mod.exe, now select that file from Desktop and hold Ctrl+X to cut it, now navigate back to your Notepad++ Installation Directory and Ctrl+V (paste it), if you get a window like this:
[image]

Just click **Continue**...

Now you want to rename the notepad++mod.exe back to notepad++.exe and you should be able to use your notepad without the menu options, you can use notepad++_BACKUP to modify your theme settings.

Though I have disabled the toolbar via Preferences so I use shortcuts like Ctrl+O to open or Ctrl+Alt+S to Save As, you can do so too.

Here is the result:
[image]

Comment: Oh wait, one of the screenshots looks like it's also possible to edit the menu there. I didn't check myself whether it works, since I barely use Windows anymore, but I'll mark it as accepted, because that comes closest to what I wanted.

Comment: Yes you can modify the menu items too. Thanks and good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

To prevent wrapping menu with many items in slim windows, rename your **Windows** menu item to **W**, **Plugins** to **P**, etc... You get the idea.

It is not possible to remove menu items without special plugin, they are hard-wired. But renaming could help to address main problem.

In your Notepad++ directory, there is a folder **localization** containing file **english_customizable.xml**, if it was installed with Notepad++ (if not, it can be added later by just running the installer again). Edit the menu titles there, you can find them in first 20 lines of the file.

In **Preferences** window, switch the language to **English (customizable)**. To reload the file (after edits), just switch to any other language and then back or restart Notepad++.

You immediately get another convenience: switch to **English** any time you want full item labels and back to **English (customizable)** for short menu item labels.

After you are satisfied with the result, backup the file so updates of Notepad++ won't overwrite your work.

Comment: That's a good idea! I could even rename menu items I don't want to " ". I marked it as accepted for now, if it any point in the future there will be a plugin for that, I'll change that.

Comment: @Fabian – you can always download the source, comment out unwanted menu items and re-compile your own build of Notepad++ – without being dependent on a plugin.

Comment: A small bit of customisation is possible: In Settings->Shortcut mapper->Run commands, it's possible to remove entries from the "Run" menu.

Comment: A problem with this solution: First it works, but when I restart Notepad++, it switches back to normal English.

Comment: @Fabian – all right, if going into such level of detail, it is also possible to disable (programming) languages.

Comment: I can already hide languages, it's in the settings. That's enough for me.

Comment: Ok, this is getting ridiculous. I renamed a menu to "" in english.xml, english_customizable.xml and %APPDATA%\Notepad++\nativeLang.xml, but it's still there after restarting. Where does it get the text from?

Comment: @Fabian - disable languages - yes, I meant in settings. Regarding menu label - not sure which one do you mean.

Comment: Ok, got it: I reinstalled Notepad++ with "English (customizable)" included, then it kept the language visually, but not really. I switched the language back to "English", closed Notepad++, started it as administrator, set the language to "English (customizable)" and restarted Notepad++ again, this time it actually kept it.

Comment: I fixed it, but I still don't really know how the problem worked. I made a program search through every single file on my PC for the string "Open Containing Folder" and it wasn't anywhere except in those three files. It was contained in some longer strings, but I highly doubt that Notepad++ takes some random system file, extracts half a string from it and labels its menus after that.

Comment: Actually, changing "English (customizable)" doesn't help, it's only %APPDATA%\Notepad++\nativeLang.xml. So do I have to do all these steps to get customizable English into it, just to ignore it and change the other file? That's so weird. But now I did so many steps that I'm not confident enough to change your answer, because I'm not 100% sure if that's really what caused it to finally work.

Comment: Some things don't get changed, even if I change it in nativeLang and English customizable, for example most settings.

Comment: Ok, no, the settings actually have to be renamed to " ", while most other labels can be renamed to "" without problems. So many inconsistencies!

Comment: @Fabian – you know, this was not intended and therefore not tested functionality. But I also noticed, that adding (not removing) too many characters into that file causes that the entire content of the file is being ignored from some point.

Comment: Interesting. But that's not a problem for me, I only shortened some strings (most of them to " "). Now my menu looks really funny, because about 80% of the menu items are just blank lines.

Comment: Copied english_customizable.xml as suggested and it alone solved my issue of TextFX missing from the menu after I updated. I do suggest either reinstalling plugins or cleaning/adding to english_customizable.xml settings it may be missing from english.xml to get expected results.